# String cannot be converted to JSON - Android

Tags: java, android, json

I have am trying to convert my response from a POST to JSON. And here is what I am doing:

```
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line;
StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(line).append("\r");
}
rd.close();
Log.i(TAG, response.toString());
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
```

But then I get error `java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

But if I make a string, `String string;` and then I paste the what I logged and set it equal to `string`, and then try

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(string);
```

It works, so why is it working when I paste the logged response, but not when I just use `response.toString();`?

In the logcat it looks like this `{"url": "www.google.com"}`. And then when I paste it into `string = "{\"url\": \"www.google.com\"}";`

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you show your response please

Comment: Please post the Json response you are getting from the server.

Comment: *Where* do you get the error you describe? Is it a compile-time error? An execution-time error? Which line? Have you tried *not* including the `\r` between lines? Is it possible that there's an unprintable character somewhere in the data?

Comment: Maybe after executing of this line in the while loop `response.append(line).append("\n");` you become some unexpected new lines in your response and the JSONObject doesn't know how to manage them and maybe when you paste the response from logcat, you eliminate these lines. Try to add `.trim()` to the `response.toString()`

Comment: @JonSkeet is it execution-time error on the line `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());`

Comment: @GabriellaAngelova I tried taking out the `"\n"` and added `.trim()` it didnt work

Comment: Can you please post the logcat with the exception after trying to execute `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());` ?

Comment: I figure out the problem but not sure how to solve it, the problem is that the response is printing an extra charter so, `response.toString() = "a{"url": "www.google.com"}"`, BUT I havent solved my problem, how could I remove this "a" infront of the JSON, is there a way to just return the JSON data?

Comment: Log.i(TAG, response.toString()); print what?

Comment: show the log for this tag

Comment: @AngadTiwari it is `a{"url": "www.google.com"}` or sometime `aadsf{"url": "www.google.com"}`

Comment: @jamesbrown ...this string is not valid json string...first try to valid your json on pro.jsonlint.com....both are invalid json

Comment: @AngadTiwari I know there both invaild, my question is how should I remove the characters infront of the {} so that they become vaild

Comment: @jamesbrown ... rainash answer is right...but its not the right way.... this should not be come from server...the response must be a proper json for future aspect

Comment: @AngadTiwari why must the server return proper JSON?

Comment: @jamesbrown its good habit rather than returning improper response type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met this problem before, try this:

```
new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
```

or

```
if (response != null && response.startsWith("\ufeff")) {  
     in = in.substring(1);  
}
```

the response from server contains a BOM header

Comment: what if it is longer than 1 character? or isnt alwasys an "a", as sometimes its longer or a different character?

Answer (score 0):

```
public JSONObject(java.lang.String source)
           throws JSONException
```

Construct a JSONObject from a source JSON text string.

`source` - **A string beginning with { (left brace) and ending with } (right brace)**.

So while doing `response.toString()` if the string do not start with `{` and close with `}` then it will throw Exception.

Comment: okay but how can, I either jsut retun the JSON, or remove the begining string

Comment: @jamesbrown you can do something like this `String result = "{" + response.substring(response.indexOf("{") + 1, response.indexOf("}")) + "}";` to remove begning String.

Comment: and then pass the result to JSONObject